# FindResource returning 0

Tags: c++, resources

I'm trying to make my own resource class, when I test it FindResource always returns 0

```
HRSRC RESOURCE_MANAGER::GetFile(char* name,int ID)
{

    return FindResource(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(ID), name);
}
```

Inside my Resource.rc i have the following

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// BIN
//

1337                    BIN                         "C:\\Users\\John\\Desktop\\TestFolder\\TestFile.exe"
#endif    //resources
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

And this is how i call it:

```
HRSRC hResource = RESOURCE_MANAGER::GetFile("BIN", 1337);
```

Comment: Docs tell you to call GetLastError. Did you get the module parameter right?

Comment: Just check if it is actually there.  In Visual Studio use File + Open + File and select your EXE.  You should see the "BIN" node and a sub-node labeled 1337.  If you don't see it then your code can never work either.